# Asp net mvc. HttpClient call gets stuck (does not return)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I've battled this problem for days now. I have a solution with two projects: one MVC and one WebApi. In the MVC I do rest calls to the webapi through an instance of HttpClient, but unfortunately the program gets stuck in `await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("Products");`:

```
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {

        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public ProductsController(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        // GET: Products
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

            var ProductList = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("Products");
            return View(ProductList);
        }
    }
```

HttpClient instance is injected as singleton through Ninject.

I have read about blocking/deadlocking async calls, but I'm not sure this is the case, or if it is I have no idea how to solve it, having tried various hacks I read about.

```
    public class NinjectResolver : System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;
        private static HttpClient httpClient;

        public NinjectResolver()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(HttpClientBaseAddress.Address);
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
        private void AddBindings()
        {
            this._kernel.Bind<HttpClient>().ToConstant(httpClient).InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectResolver());
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

One last edit before I answer my own question:

```
    public static class HttpClientBaseAddress
    {
        public static string Address { get; } = "http://localhost:44356/api/";
    }
```

Comment: Is this the .NET built-in `HttpClient`? Can you also add the part of code where you configure it?

Comment: @trashr0x, yes, the builtin HttpClient. I posted some more code now.

Comment: Have you used an HTTP debugger like Fiddler to see if the server actually responds?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I did not because I didn't know about this kind of debugging. Some time within tomorrow I'll let you know. Thanks.
I can just say for now that the web page with the call to the api loads until HttpClient times out.
The expected behavious would be if I'm not mistaken ProductList empty with an error about CORS in the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem setting the base address as:

http**s**://localhost:44356/api/